# ¿Cómo hacer esta consulta de datos a una API desde MVC?

Tags: sql, ajax, asp.net, mvc, razor

espero se encuentren muy bien, estoy teniendo un problema con una consulta hacia una API del clima. Es para un proyecto de mi curso.

Ya lo tengo todo casi terminado, pero, necesito agregar el objeto de "stations" para ser consultado por el utilizador.

En mi codigo, cuando tu escribes "New York" o alguna ciudad o pais, el te mostrara todos los dados con rango de tiempo (hoy, manana, o en una semana), todo aparece perfectamente, pero cuando, cuando estoy intentando acceder a Stations, especificamente "f1564" (el cual tiene los datos que necesito), me arroja el Error Post 500, tras consultar el formulario.

Consegui arreglar el problema con el codigo que me dio el profesor, pero, me parece poco para sumar experiencia a mi proyecto. Por lo tanto, cree una clase en un modelo para poder obtener lo que necesito:

```
public class WeatherStations
{
    public double? Distance { get; set; }
    public double? Latitude { get; set; }
    public double? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string? useCount { get; set; }
    public double? Quality { get; set; }
    public double? Contribution { get; set; }

}
```

POSTERIORMENTE: he desarrollado la consulta de la API con dicha clase:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FormAPI (WeatherModel weather)
    {
        // Timeline api
        string API_URL;
        switch(weather.Period){

            case "Today":
                API_URL = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/" + weather.locationName + "/today?unitGroup=metric&key=UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4&contentType=json";
                break;

            case "Tomorrow":
                API_URL = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/" + weather.locationName + "/tomorrow?unitGroup=metric&key=UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4&contentType=json";
                break;

            case "Next 7 Days":
                API_URL = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/" + weather.locationName + "/next7days?unitGroup=metric&key=UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4&contentType=json";

                break;

            case "Next 15 Days":
                API_URL = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/" + weather.locationName + "/next15days?unitGroup=metric&key=UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4&contentType=json";

                break;

            default:
                API_URL = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/" + weather.locationName + "/today?unitGroup=metric&key=UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4&contentType=json";
                break;

        }
        // HTTP Request API (Import API)
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, API_URL); // API method

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request); // Consult with API
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Status isSuccess
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Convert response to string to be read

        //string result = "";
        dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(body);
        var resultList = new List<WeatherResults>();
        

        foreach (var item in jsonObject.days)
        {
            var result = new WeatherResults();
            result.ForecastDate = item.datetime;
            result.Temperature = item.temp;
            result.HighTemperature = item.tempmax;
            result.LowTemperature = item.tempmin;
            result.WindSpeed = item.windspeed;
            result.Sunset = item.sunset;
            result.Sunrise = item.sunrise;
            result.Conditions = item.conditions;
            resultList.Add(result);


            // Add to database 
            WeatherDB forecastRecord = new WeatherDB();
            forecastRecord.ForecastDate = item.datetime;
            forecastRecord.Temperature = item.temp;
            forecastRecord.HighTemperature = item.tempmax;
            forecastRecord.LowTemperature = item.tempmin;
            forecastRecord.WindSpeed = item.windspeed;
            forecastRecord.Sunset = item.sunrise;
            forecastRecord.Sunrise = item.sunrise;
            forecastRecord.Conditions = item.conditions;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(forecastRecord);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
               
            }
        }

        
        -> ****var resultListStation = new List<WeatherStations>();
        var weatherStations = jsonObject.currentConditions["stations"];
        
        foreach (var stationID in weatherStations) {
            var resultStation = new WeatherStations();
            //Station details are distance, latitude, longitude, useCount, id, name, quality, contribution
            resultStation.Distance = weatherStations[stationID].distance;
            resultStation.Longitude = weatherStations[stationID].latitude;
            resultStation.Longitude = weatherStations[stationID].longitude;
            resultStation.useCount = weatherStations[stationID].useCount;
            resultStation.Quality = weatherStations[stationID].quality;
            resultStation.Contribution = weatherStations[stationID].contribution;
            resultListStation.Add(resultStation);
        }
        ViewBag.showStations = resultListStation;**** <-
        ViewBag.Address = jsonObject.resolvedAddress;
        ViewBag.showResults = resultList;

        return View("Results", weather);
    }
```

Sin embargo, al hacer el llamado, ocurre el error post 500, aqui les anexare el mi codigo completo, y como aparece en mi html (en su invocacion)
Quisiera saber como me pudieran ayudar.

Cabe resaltar que creo encontrar el problema, y es debido a como esta siendo llamado en AJAX, de esta forma lo estoy implementando: **

```
Results API with AJAX
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Manejador del evento submit del formulario
    $('#ApiForm').submit(function (event) {
            // Prevenir la acción por defecto del formulario (cargar una nueva página)
            event.preventDefault();
            // Obtener la información del formulario
            var formData = $('#ApiForm').serialize();
            // Realizar la petición Ajax
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Home/FormAPI", // Ruta del controlador y la acción
                data: formData,
                success: function (result) {
                    // Actualizar el contenido del contenedor de resultados
                    $('#results_api').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

** y por último, esta es mi llamada en el formulario del html: **

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("FormAPI", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {id = "ApiForm"}))
    {
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(weather => weather.locationName, new {
        @class="displayForm_layout d-flex",
        @id = "search_Input",
        placeholder = "Enter Location",
        style = "text-align: center"
    })
```

**el error persiste, he intentando mejorarlo, y con ayuda el profesor hemos investigado, sin embargo, el error continua cada vez que realizo la consulta en el formulario, post 500**

**cabe resaltar, que cuando no coloco aquel bloque de codigo (que tiene `-> *** *** <-`) el codigo funciona perfectamente sin error alguno**

Pienso que es porque Ajax solo hace un llamado una vez, y no vuelve a repetir el llamado con el resto del código

Espero me puedan ayudar!

Anexo aqui lo que el profesor consultó de la API

```
 "currentConditions": {
  "datetime": "13:52:10",
  "datetimeEpoch": 1679493130,
  "temp": 18,
  "feelslike": 18,
  "humidity": 75.6,
  "dew": 13.6,
  "precip": 0,
  "precipprob": 0,
  "snow": 0,
  "snowdepth": 0,
  "preciptype": null,
  "windgust": null,
  "windspeed": 25.6,
  "winddir": 31,
  "pressure": 1019,
  "visibility": 10,
  "cloudcover": 27.2,
  "solarradiation": 704,
  "solarenergy": 2.5,
  "uvindex": 7,
  "conditions": "Partially cloudy",
  "icon": "partly-cloudy-day",
  "stations": [
   "LPPS",
   "F1564",
   "LPMA"
  ]
```

noten que el f1564, es simplemente un elemento sin nada, sin embargo, el que yo estoy queriendo consultar es este:

```
"stations": {
  "D3478": {
   "distance": 28514,
   "latitude": 32.734,
   "longitude": -17.194,
   "useCount": 0,
   "id": "D3478",
   "name": "DW3478 Funchal PT",
   "quality": 0,
   "contribution": 0
  },
  "F1564": {
   "distance": 4883,
   "latitude": 32.678,
   "longitude": -16.945,
   "useCount": 0,
   "id": "F1564",
   "name": "FW1564 Funchal PT",
   "quality": 0,
   "contribution": 0
  }
```

Comment: Pero el codigo 500 implica que es error del servidor no tiene nada que ver con lo que tu tengas. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500

Comment: NO TIENES QUE GRITAR. Y lo otro, si da error 500, una de dos: a) es culpa del servidor porque está fallando; b) estás enviando los datos en un formato incorrecto y matas al servidor, je. EN cualquier caso, es falla del lado del servidor. Te sugiero que publiques los errores completos (hay algún mensaje junto con la respuesta HTTP 500?)

Comment: Como te dice @Alfabravo en realidad tu debes preocuparte de los códigos 4XX(400, 401, etc) por que implica que estas enviando mal tu información.

Comment: Hola, si, el error es este : 

POST https://localhost:7045/Home/FormAPI 500 (y al final no me muestra nada de los resultados, ni una ni la otra consulta a la API)

Comment: De lo que me haces entender el es tu api la que esta fallando.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron varios en los comentatios, el error [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) es del servidor, tambien tu codigo se puede mejorar y saber porque te esta dando el status 500.

1. primeramente usa try catch
2. pasar la url y la api key en una variable

`var baseUrl = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/";`

```
 `var apiKey = "UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4";`
```

3. por ultimo hacer una validacion cuanto el status sea 200, y dentro del if agregar el resto de tu metodo.
4. Por ultimo revisar como estas enviando la peticion, la mayoria de las api cuanto tienen dos palabras como New York, siempre se envia con un `+`, ejemplo `New+York`, con esto indicas que solicitas los datos de la ciudad de `New York`, en otro caso cuanto no lo envias con `+` puede darte el resultado de otra ciudad o no encontrar nada

tu codigo quedaria de esta manera

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FormAPI(WeatherModel weather)
{
  var baseUrl = "https://weather.visualcrossing.com/VisualCrossingWebServices/rest/services/timeline/";
  var apiKey = "UFKQGYDB8G2C54CVAJ9JHGYY4";

  try
  {
      var API_URL = weather.Period switch {
          "Today" => $"{baseUrl}/{weather.LocationName}/today?unitGroup=metric&key={apiKey}&contentType=json",
          "Tomorrow" => $"{baseUrl}/{weather.LocationName}/tomorrow?unitGroup=metric&key=&contentType=json",
          "Next 7 Days" => $"{baseUrl}/{weather.LocationName}/next7days?unitGroup=metric&key={apiKey}&contentType=json",
          "Next 15 Days" => $"{baseUrl}/{weather.LocationName}/next15days?unitGroup=metric&key={apiKey}&contentType=json",
          _ => $"{baseUrl}/{weather.LocationName}/today?unitGroup=metric&key={apiKey}&contentType=json",
      };
      // HTTP Request API (Import API)
      var client = new HttpClient();
      var response = await client.GetAsync(API_URL);
      if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
        //aqui iria el resto de tu codigo
         // cuanto el status se acompleto, sera 200, te arrojara los resultado, 
        //por eso siempre te deberia mostrar los resultado, en caso contrario entraria al catch
         var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // Convert response to string to be read

      }

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    
      throw;
  }
}
```